# How to perform the following design operation in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Unable post the Image Because my reputation is below 10 so I will try to give an design please try to understand

My design like

|A|B|C|........|Z|

I need to perform the search based on the user clicked alphabet. How can do this operation very easy way and How can I design my page like shown in Image in asp.net.

I have an Idea like putting the buttons for every alphabet but It is very long procedure so can you please help me.

thanks,

Purna

Comment: Create labels for each of the letters, hook them to one clickeventhandler that retrieves the letter from the senderlabel and then searches for that letter.

Comment: I have given button for every alphabet I can able to perform the operation using the buttons but it is very long procedure so can you help in easy way....

Comment: Is it possible to use the datalist for design @Matthijs

Comment: @Purna: I don't think thats a possible option. It requires even more work in my eyes as it uses an xml-datastructure, rather than just text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = "btn" + i.ToString();
            btn.Text = ((char)('A' + i)).ToString();
            btn.CommandArgument = ((char)('A' + i)).ToString();
            btn.Click += btn_Click;
            dv.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
    }
    private void btn_Click(object sender, object arg)
    {
        Div1.InnerHtml += "\nClicked : " + ((Button)sender).ID;
        Div1.InnerHtml += "<br/>arg : " + ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
    }
```

CSS

```
#dv input[type="submit"] 
{
 height: 20px; 
 width: 30px; 
 margin: 2px; 
 color: blue; 
 float: left; 
 }
```

Another one way is using Listview.

```
<asp:ListView ItemPlaceholderID="Test" runat="server" ID="ListView1" > 

            <ItemTemplate> 
                <div class ="btn-search">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' /><br /> 
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:ListView>  
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1"></asp:Literal> 



 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView1.ItemCommand += new EventHandler<ListViewCommandEventArgs>(ListView1_ItemCommand);
    }

    void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Literal1.Text = "You clicked the " + (String)e.CommandArgument + " button";
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var list = Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1).Select(charCode => (char)charCode).ToList();
            ListView1.DataSource = list;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I think this may help you.